# Can't load new modules/driver due to "Exec format error" / "Skipping invalid relocation target"

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, modprobe

I'm trying to update the driver for our Intel C62x Chipset QuickAssist Technology add-on card, but getting the mentioned errors when I try to load the modules.  I haven't done this in a while, but I thought the process was pretty straightforward:

1. Stop the QAT services [ ok ]
2. `uninstall` the QAT driver [ ok ]
3. `modprobe -r` any remaining QAT modules [ ok ]
4. download, extract, `configure`, `make` the new QAT driver [ ok ]
5. `install` the new driver [ FAIL ]

For example:

```
# make -j16 install
[...]
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-5-amd64/build M=/usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat INSTALL_MOD_DIR=updates modules_install
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-5-amd64'
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_200xx/qat_200xx.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_200xxvf/qat_200xxvf.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_c3xxx/qat_c3xxx.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_c3xxxvf/qat_c3xxxvf.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_c4xxx/qat_c4xxx.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_c4xxxvf/qat_c4xxxvf.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_c62x/qat_c62x.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_c62xvf/qat_c62xvf.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_common/intel_qat.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_d15xx/qat_d15xx.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_d15xxvf/qat_d15xxvf.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_dh895xcc/qat_dh895xcc.ko
  INSTALL /usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_dh895xccvf/qat_dh895xccvf.ko
  DEPMOD  4.19.0-5-amd64
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-5-amd64'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001/quickassist/qat'
Creating startup and kill scripts
Copying libqat_s.so to /usr/local/lib
Copying libusdm_drv_s.so to /usr/local/lib
Copying usdm module to system drivers
Group qat already exists.
Creating udev rules
Creating module.dep file for QAT released kernel object
This will take a few moments
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/qat.service → /lib/systemd/system/qat.service.
Starting QAT service
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'qat_c62x': Exec format error
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'usdm_drv': Exec format error
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'qat_api': Exec format error
Restarting all devices.
Can not open /dev/qat_adf_ctl
Checking status of all devices.
Can not open /dev/qat_adf_ctl
    *** Error:usdm_drv module not installed ***
    *** Error:qat_api module not installed ***
    *** Error:qat_c62x module not installed ***
Can not open /dev/qat_adf_ctl
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/QAT.L.4.20.0-00001'

# modprobe -v qat_c62x
insmod /lib/modules/4.19.0-5-amd64/updates/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_common/intel_qat.ko
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'qat_c62x': Exec format error

# modprobe -v intel_qat
insmod /lib/modules/4.19.0-5-amd64/updates/drivers/crypto/qat/qat_common/intel_qat.ko
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'intel_qat': Exec format error

#
```

Meanwhile, the system log shows:

```
<date> <host> kernel: [<uptime>] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 000000005c09d38d, val ffffffffc09ba2fe
<date> <host> kernel: [<uptime>] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000000690eef73, val ffffffffc0b572fe
<date> <host> kernel: [<uptime>] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 000000007d30ad16, val ffffffffc0c862fe
<date> <host> kernel: [<uptime>] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000000671d2da7, val ffffffffc0cd82fe
<date> <host> kernel: [<uptime>] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 0000000072877855, val ffffffffc0d2a2fe
```

What are these errors even talking about and what is the cause and possible solutions?

Thanks so much!